# Oracle Max Date query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table called maximo_audit and I am trying to only count the most recent actiondate record with an approvalstatus of N. I wrote this query but it is taking forever to run

```
SELECT COUNT (*)
  FROM (SELECT   MAX (actiondate)
            FROM timedetail t JOIN maximo_audit m ON m.recordid = t.quantity
           WHERE approvalstatus = 'N'
             AND t.tsdate BETWEEN '8-dec-2013' AND '21-dec-2013'
             AND task2 IS NOT NULL
        --and recordid = '1781891'
        GROUP BY m.recordid
          HAVING MAX (actiondate) IN (SELECT MAX (actiondate)
                                        FROM maximo_audit ma
                                       WHERE ma.recordid = m.recordid))
```

Comment: Could you please provide a table structure for these two tables and a few sample records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often using explicit joins helps the optimizer.  You can also replace the subquery with a simpler `count(distinct)`.

```
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.recordid)
  FROM timedetail t JOIN
       maximo_audit m
       ON m.recordid = t.quantity JOIN
       (select ma.recordid, max(actiondate) as actiondate
        from maximo_audit ma
        group by ma.recordid
       ) ma
       on ma.recordid = m.recordid and ma.actiondate = m.actiondate
  WHERE approvalstatus = 'N' AND
        t.tsdate BETWEEN '8-dec-2013' AND '21-dec-2013' AND
        task2 IS NOT NULL;
```

The `having` clause can be replaced with a join because when the maximum of the action date equals something, then one of the action dates will match that value.